# Creating local copy of an online Potential Flood Inundation Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion, flood

I am completely stuck, usually I can figure out how to create a local copy of hosted services, but this one I can't seem to get anything to work and any suggestions would be great.

Currently I can access the layer using ArcGIS-Pro but can only query by point. I would like to create a local raster layer or .GDB .

Trying to create a local copy for future reference.

Here is the link:
http://www.horrycounty.org/gisweb/rest/services/Public/FloodAreasFlorence/MapServer

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't much you can do from the URL you have. This service is all raster layers which will essentially serve up "pictures" of the map. You'll need to go after the data through other means. Contacting them directly, other data providers, etc.